# Can you use Python with MS Machine Learning in SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: python, machine-learning, sql-server-2016

I want to use Microsoft's Machine Learning Services in SQL SERVER 2016, specifically to leverage Python, NOT R.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2017 (or greater) Setup is required if you want to install Machine Learning Services with R, [Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-2017), or Java language support.

You will only find R support for 2016.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @DMellons answer; Java is supported in SQL 2019 and up. So:

- SQL 2016: R
- SQL 2017: R, Python
- SQL 2019: R, Python, Java, more languages may come.